# Long table - align in comma and wrap text in titles

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

I am trying to align my last two columns at comma and also the text of titles to be in wrap mode but....I can't do it. any suggestions? I defined a \newcolumntype but I don't know how to combine it with the specific page.

```
\vspace*{0.5cm}
\newcolumntype{,}{D{,}{,}{9}}
\begin{longtable}{p{3cm} p{3cm}} c{p{1cm}} ,p{3cm} ,p{3cm}}

\multicolumn{5}{ c }{Begin of Table}\\
\noalign{\vskip 0.5cm} 
\toprule
Wrap Text Text Text&Wrap Text Text Text&text&Wrap Text Text Text&Wrap Text Text Text\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\noalign{\vskip 0.3cm} 
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Continuation of Table %\ref{}}\\
\noalign{\vskip 0.5cm} 
\toprule
Wrap Text Text Text&Wrap Text Text Text&text&Wrap Text Text Text&Wrap Text     Text Text\\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\noalign{\vskip 0.2cm} 
\multicolumn{5}{ c }{End of Table}\\
\endlastfoot

6&0,05&1&-0,061310591&-0,06\\
6&0,05&1&-0,054844044&-0,05\\
1&0,07&2&-0,054136608&-0,05\\
4&0,05&2&-0,046701643&-0,05\\
4&0,03&5&0,028336245&0,03\\
6&0,09&1&-0,08889456&-0,09\\
2&0,03&1&-0,04118333&-0,04\\
1&0,05&5&0,042491209&0,04\\
2&0,01&1&-0,02884842&-0,03\\
4&0,03&5&0,029565063&0,03\\
2&0,05&1&-0,05409358&-0,05\\
1&0,07&2&-0,055479359&-0,06\\
2&0,09&1&-0,084154537&-0,08\\
1&0,05&5&0,043112787&0,04\\
4&0,05&2&-0,04090668&-0,04\\
\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code may achieve your objectives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,dcolumn,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{,}{,}{#1}} % for alignment on decimal marker
\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ l d{1.2} l d{2.9} d{2.2} }

\caption{My fancy table}\label{tab:fancy} \\
\toprule
\mc{2cm}{Wrap Text Text Text}&
\mc{3cm}{Wrap Text Text Text}&
\mc{1cm}{text}&
\mc{3cm}{Wrap Text Text Text}&
\mc{2cm}{Wrap Text Text Text}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{l}{Table \ref{tab:fancy}, continued} \\ 
\addlinespace
\toprule
\mc{2cm}{Wrap Text Text Text}&
\mc{3cm}{Wrap Text Text Text}&
\mc{1cm}{text}&
\mc{3cm}{Wrap Text Text Text}&
\mc{2cm}{Wrap Text Text Text}\\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r}{(Continued on following page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

6&0,05&1&-0,061310591&-0,06\\
6&0,05&1&-0,054844044&-0,05\\
1&0,07&2&-0,054136608&-0,05\\
4&0,05&2&-0,046701643&-0,05\\
4&0,03&5&0,028336245&0,03\\
6&0,09&1&-0,08889456&-0,09\\
2&0,03&1&-0,04118333&-0,04\\
1&0,05&5&0,042491209&0,04\\
2&0,01&1&-0,02884842&-0,03\\
4&0,03&5&0,029565063&0,03\\
2&0,05&1&-0,05409358&-0,05\\
1&0,07&2&-0,055479359&-0,06\\
2&0,09&1&-0,084154537&-0,08\\
1&0,05&5&0,043112787&0,04\\
4&0,05&2&-0,04090668&-0,04\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, can you explain the syntax of \newcolumntype and \newcommand. You are amazing....really thank you my friend...

Comment: @apollon18 - The `\newcolumntype` instruction creates a new column type, named `d`, suitable to align numbers on their respective decimal markers. `\newcommand` creates a new macro -- in this case, a macro that takes two arguments to encase the 2nd argument in a `p` column of a certain width  (the macro's first argument). The `\multicolumn{1}{<type>}{<content>}` instruction serves to override the default column type (`l` or `d`) and to assign a different column type (here: `p`).